# How to write Test cases for useEffect Hook in React using Jest & Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-hooks

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const InputComponent = ({ item, data }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  // Binding values for Edit based on unique Key
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data[item.field] && data[item.field] !== 'undefined') {
      setValue(data[item.field]);
    }
  }, [data,item.field]);
  //On change setting state
  const setState = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className='Input-Containter' data-test='InputBox-tbl-evt'>
      <input
        data-test='input-ele'
        type='text'
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setState(e)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
InputComponent.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.object,
  data: PropTypes.object
};

InputComponent.defaultProps = {
    data: {
        id: '1',
        name: 'd'
    },
    item:{
        field: 'id',
    }
};

export default InputComponent;
```

> Can someone help me How to test for setValue() in useEffect
>
> -> Updated complete code for this Component
>
> -> Component will take some data for binding values into input element & in the same
>
> > component we can edit values in it as-well.

Comment: you should not go this way. it's example of "test implementation" trap and such a thing does not give you any value. without more complete code I cannot provide snippet but in general: you trigger some change by providing some props/simulating events and then validate what component returns(in your case - validating that whatever depends on `value` has been changed)

Comment: @skyboyer: I have added complete code. If you have free time please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's take closer look onto `useEffect` section. What does it mean?

1. if any of prop is changed
2. and combination of new values are given some meaningful value(not undefined)
3. we initialize `input`'s value based on those props even if we have to override custom value

How to test that? Changing prop(s) and validating `input`'s `value`.

Based on that we may have up to 3(changed only first prop, only second or both) * 2 (if result is `undefined` or not) * 2 (if there has been already custom value provided and stored in `useState` or not) = 12. But I believe exhaustive testing is not a good way. So I'd put most checks in single test case:

```
it('re-init value for nested input after props changes', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<InputComponent />);
  function getInput(wrapper) {
    return wrapper.find("input").prop("value");
  }
  expect(getInput(wrapper).props("value")).toEqual("1"); // based on default props 
  getInput(wrapper).props().onChange({ target: {value: "initial"} }); // imitating manual change
  expect(getInput(wrapper).props("value")).toEqual("initial"); 
  wrapper.setProps({data: {a: "some-a", b: "undefined"} });
  expect(getInput(wrapper).props("value")).toEqual("initial");
  wrapper.setProps({ item: { field: "c" } }); // data[item.field] is undefined
  expect(getInput(wrapper).props("value")).toEqual("initial");
  wrapper.setProps({ item: {field: "b" } }); // data[item.field] is "undefined"
  expect(getInput(wrapper).props("value")).toEqual("initial");
  wrapper.setProps({ item: {field: "a" } }); // data[item.field] is meaningful
  expect(getInput(wrapper).props("value")).toEqual("some-a");
});
```

As for `getValue` helper - it's needed cause we cannot just memoize `input` element itself like:

```
const wrapper = mount(...);
const input = wrapper.find("input");
...
expect(input.prop("value")).toEqual();
...
expect(input.prop("value")).toEqual();
```

Details can be found in [Enzyme's docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/common-issues.html#nested-component-may-not-be-updated-after-wrapper-updates). Or just know we need to re-run `find` after any update.

Also beware Enzyme's `setProps` does not replace current props [but update them by merging](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/setProps.html)(as well as React's `setState` does with state).

Comment: Thanks a lot my test cases passed